# Android upload image to amzon s3 Showing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed error

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, image-uploading

I am uploading image to Amazon S3 from gallery via android app.

it showing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed error

I have added my code below ,please help me solve it.

Error i am Getting like this

```
06-17 17:23:22.908: W/System.err(27214): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
06-17 17:23:22.909: W/System.err(27214):    at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
06-17 17:23:22.909: W/System.err(27214):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(Unknown Source)
06-17 17:23:22.910: W/System.err(27214):    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(Unknown Source)
06-17 17:23:22.910: W/System.err(27214):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(Unknown Source)
06-17 17:23:22.910: W/System.err(27214):    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.uploadPart(Unknown Source)
06-17 17:23:22.911: W/System.err(27214):    at com.readystatesoftware.simpl3r.Uploader.start(Uploader.java:162)
06-17 17:23:22.911: W/System.err(27214):    at com.readystatesoftware.simpl3r.example.UploadService.onHandleIntent(UploadService.java:103)
06-17 17:23:22.911: W/System.err(27214):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
06-17 17:23:22.911: W/System.err(27214):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-17 17:23:22.912: W/System.err(27214):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-17 17:23:22.912: W/System.err(27214):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

UploadService.java

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService {

    public static final String ARG_FILE_PATH = "file_path";
    public static final String UPLOAD_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION = "com.readystatesoftware.simpl3r.example.UPLOAD_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION";
    public static final String UPLOAD_CANCELLED_ACTION = "com.readystatesoftware.simpl3r.example.UPLOAD_CANCELLED_ACTION";
    public static final String S3KEY_EXTRA = "s3key";
    public static final String PERCENT_EXTRA = "percent";
    public static final String MSG_EXTRA = "msg";

    private static final int NOTIFY_ID_UPLOAD = 1337;

    private AmazonS3Client s3Client;
    private Uploader uploader;

    private NotificationManager nm;

    public UploadService() {
        super("simpl3r-example-upload");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                new BasicAWSCredentials(getString(R.string.s3_access_key), getString(R.string.s3_secret)));
        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
        f.addAction(UPLOAD_CANCELLED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(uploadCancelReceiver, f);
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


        String filePath = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_FILE_PATH);
        File fileToUpload = new File(filePath);
        final String s3ObjectKey = md5(filePath);
        String s3BucketName = getString(R.string.s3_bucket);

        final String msg = "Uploading " + s3ObjectKey + "...";

        // create a new uploader for this file
        uploader = new Uploader(this, s3Client, s3BucketName, s3ObjectKey, fileToUpload);

    /*  File theFile = new File(filePath);
         PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal, keyName, theFile);
         putObjectRequest.withMetadata(objectMetadata);*/


        // listen for progress updates and broadcast/notify them appropriately
        uploader.setProgressListener(new UploadProgressListener() {         
            @Override
            public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent progressEvent,
                    long bytesUploaded, int percentUploaded) {

                Notification notification = buildNotification(msg, percentUploaded);
                nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID_UPLOAD, notification);
                broadcastState(s3ObjectKey, percentUploaded, msg);
            }
        });

        // broadcast/notify that our upload is starting
        Notification notification = buildNotification(msg, 0);
        nm.notify(NOTIFY_ID_UPLOAD, notification);
        broadcastState(s3ObjectKey, 0, msg);

        try {
            String s3Location = uploader.start(); // initiate the upload
            broadcastState(s3ObjectKey, -1, "File successfully uploaded to " + s3Location);
        } catch (UploadIterruptedException uie) {
            broadcastState(s3ObjectKey, -1, "User interrupted");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            broadcastState(s3ObjectKey, -1, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        nm.cancel(NOTIFY_ID_UPLOAD);
        unregisterReceiver(uploadCancelReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void broadcastState(String s3key, int percent, String msg) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(UPLOAD_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString(S3KEY_EXTRA, s3key);
        b.putInt(PERCENT_EXTRA, percent);
        b.putString(MSG_EXTRA, msg);
        intent.putExtras(b);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private Notification buildNotification(String msg, int progress) {  
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setTicker(msg);
        builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        builder.setContentText(msg);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_uploading);
        builder.setOngoing(true);
        builder.setProgress(100, progress, false);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        return builder.build();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver uploadCancelReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (uploader != null) {
                uploader.interrupt();
            }
        }
    };

    private String md5(String s) {
        try {
            // create MD5 Hash
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(s.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            // create Hex String
            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i=0; i<messageDigest.length; i++)
                hexString.append(Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]));
            return hexString.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;

    Button select;
    Button interrupt;
    ProgressBar progress;
    TextView status;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_select);
        interrupt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_interrupt);
        progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);

        select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // start file chooser
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file to upload"),
                        FILE_SELECT_CODE);
            }
        });

        interrupt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // interrupt any active upload
                Intent intent = new Intent(UploadService.UPLOAD_CANCELLED_ACTION);
                sendBroadcast(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        IntentFilter f = new IntentFilter();
        f.addAction(UploadService.UPLOAD_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(uploadStateReceiver, f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        unregisterReceiver(uploadStateReceiver);
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
                // get path of selected file 
                Uri uri = data.getData();
                String path = getPathFromContentUri(uri);
                Log.d("S3", "uri=" + uri.toString());
                Log.d("S3", "path=" + path);
                // initiate the upload
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, UploadService.class);
                intent.putExtra(UploadService.ARG_FILE_PATH, path);
                startService(intent);
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private String getPathFromContentUri(Uri uri) {
        String path = uri.getPath();
        if (uri.toString().startsWith("content://")) {
            String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA };
            ContentResolver cr = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                try {
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        path = cursor.getString(0);
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }

        }
        return path;
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver uploadStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
            status.setText(b.getString(UploadService.MSG_EXTRA));
            int percent = b.getInt(UploadService.PERCENT_EXTRA);
            progress.setIndeterminate(percent < 0);
            progress.setProgress(percent);
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: You should provide at least the first few lines of stack trace for context. Also, I notice that you appear to have AWS credentials, specifically a secret key, stored in your app's resource bundle. That's not a safe way to get credentials into your app.

Comment: iam searched in google not able to find proper code for this. help me what to do.

Comment: Cognito is a better way to get temporary credentials into your app although there is some setup involved. On the transfer issue, I don't know what your 'uploader' class looks like but the SDK offers a TransferManager - see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/s3/transfermanager/TransferManager.html.

Comment: so i can,t solve this error in this code?

Comment: else Suggest me any working demo for upload image to amazon s3 from android app. i  searched but not able to find proper demo

Comment: The bug may be in your code or in the SDK you're using. That exception seems to be a common one, and related to extracting content from an entity more than once (when only one time is allowed), hence the state exception. Are you using the latest version of the mobile SDK? Older versions had a bug just like this, for example: http://blog.uws.ie/2012/11/illegalstateexception-in-amazon-sdk-for-java/. But in the long run you would be well-advised to migrate to the TransferManager.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80782/discussion-between-kumar-and-jarmod).

Comment: You can also find a sample of the transfer manager here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running a sample from Github https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-simpl3r. The SDK version 1.4.3 is released 3 years ago. It uses Android's built-in Apache HttpClient which is very buggy and has been deprecated by Android. The 'Content has been consumed' issue can occur sometimes.

Please update the SDK to the latest version v2.2.2. It should be backward compatible. Check it out at http://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/.